# Expressing type relationships and avoiding long type parameter lists in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I have this situation (drastically simplified):

```
interface IPoint<TPoint> 
   where TPoint:IPoint<TPoint>
{
   //example method
   TPoint Translate(TPoint offset);
}

interface IGrid<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TPoint:IPoint<T
   where TDualPoint:Ipoint
{
   TDualPoint GetDualPoint(TPoint point, /* Parameter specifying direction */);
}
```

Here is typical implementation:

```
class HexPoint : IPoint<HexPoint> { ... }
class TriPoint : IPoint<TriPoint> { ... }

class HexGrid : IGrid<HexPoint, TriPoint> { ... }
class TriGrid : IGrid<TriPoint, HexPoint> { ... }
```

So on a `HexGrid`, the client can make a call to get a point on a dual grid, with exactly the right type:

```
TriPoint dual = hexGrid.GetDualPoint(hexPoint, North);
```

So far so good; the client does not need to know anything about the type how the two points relate, all she needs to know is that on a `HexGrid` the method `GetDualPoint` returns a `TriPoint`.

Except...

I have a class full of generic algorithms, that operate on `IGrid`s, for example:

```
static List<TPoint> CalcShortestPath<TPoint, TDualPoint>(
   IGrid<TPoint, TDualPoint> grid, 
   TPoint start, 
   TPoint goal) 
{...}
```

Now, the client suddenly has to know the little detail that the dual point of a `HexPoint` is a `TriPoint`, and we need to specify it as part of the type parameter list, even though it does not strictly matter for this algorithm:

```
static List<TPoint> CalcShortestPath<TPoint, *>(
   IGrid<TPoint, *> grid, 
   TPoint start, 
   TPoint goal) 
{...}
```

Ideally, I would like to make DualPoint a "property" of the type `IPoint`, so that `HexPoint.DualPoint` *is* the type `TriPoint`.

Something that allows IGrid to look like this:

```
interface IGrid<TPoint> 
   where TPoint:IPoint<TPoint> 
   //and TPoint has "property" DualPoint where DualPoint implements IPoint...
{
   IGrid<TPoint.DualPoint> GetDualGrid();
}
```

and the function `CalcShortestPath` like this

```
static List<TPoint> CalcShortestPath<TPoint>(
   IGrid<TPoint> grid, 
   TPoint start, 
   TPoint goal) 
{...}
```

Of course, this is not possible, as far as I know.

But is there a way I can change my design to mimic this somehow? So that

- It expresses the relationship between the two types
- It prevents excessive type argument lists
- It prevents clients having to think too hard about how the concrete type "specialises" the type parameters of the interface the type implements.

---

To give an indication of why this becomes a real problem: In my library `IGrid` actually has 4 type parameters, `IPoint` has 3, and both will potentially increase (up to 6 and 5). (Similar relations hold between most of these type parameters.)

Explicit overloads instead of generics for the algorithms are not practical: there are 9 concrete implementations of each of `IGrid` and `IPoint`. Some algorithms operate on two types of grids, and hence have a tonne of type parameters. (The declaration of many functions are longer than the function body!)

The mental burden was driven home when my IDE threw away *all* the type parameters during an automatic rename, and  I had to put all the parameters back manually. It was not a mindless task; my brain was fried.

---

As requested by @Iridium, an example showing when type inference fails. Obviously, the code below does not do anything; it's just to illustrate compiler behaviour.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface IPoint<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TPoint:IPoint<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TDualPoint : IPoint<TDualPoint, TPoint>{}

interface IGrid<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TPoint:IPoint<TPoint, TDualPoint>
   where TDualPoint:IPoint<TDualPoint, TPoint>{}

class HexPoint : IPoint<HexPoint, TriPoint> 
{
   public HexPoint Rotate240(){ return new HexPoint();} //Normally you would rotate the point
}

class TriPoint : IPoint<TriPoint, HexPoint>{}    
class HexGrid : IGrid<HexPoint, TriPoint>{}

static class Algorithms
{  
   public static IEnumerable<TPoint> TransformShape<TPoint, TDualPoint>(
      IEnumerable<TPoint> shape, 
      Func<TPoint, TPoint> transform)

   where TPoint : IPoint<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TDualPoint : IPoint<TDualPoint, TPoint> 
   {
      return 
         from TPoint point in shape
            select transform(point);
   }

   public static IEnumerable<TPoint> TransformShape<TPoint, TDualPoint>(
      IGrid<TPoint, TDualPoint> grid, 
      IEnumerable<TPoint> shape, 
      Func<TPoint, TPoint> transform)

   where TPoint : IPoint<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TDualPoint : IPoint<TDualPoint, TPoint> 
   {
      return 
         from TPoint point in shape
            //where transform(point) is in grid
            select transform(point);
   }
}

class UserCode
{  
   public static void UserMethod()
   {
      HexGrid hexGrid = new HexGrid();      
      List<HexPoint> hexPointShape = new List<HexPoint>(); //Add some items

      //Compiles
      var rotatedShape1 = Algorithms.TransformShape(
         hexGrid,
         hexPointShape, 
         point => point.Rotate240()).ToList();

      //Compiles   
      var rotatedShape2 = Algorithms.TransformShape<HexPoint, TriPoint>(
         hexPointShape, 
         point => point.Rotate240()).ToList(); 

      //Does not compile   
      var rotatedShape3 = Algorithms.TransformShape(
          hexPointShape, 
          point => point.Rotate240()).ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, your current version would probably not work - the return type of `HexGrid.GetDualGrid()` is an `IGrid<TriPoint, HexPoint>` - which cannot be cast implicitly to `TriGrid`. You already need a third type parameter for `IGrid`.

Comment: Thank you, the error came in with the "simplification". I corrected the code and explanation (but the example does seem a bit weaker now). I would have liked to be able to just be able to have it worked like that (it's actually another illustration of the overall problem...)

Comment: You mention that the `CalcShortestPath` requires the client to know that the dual point of `HexPoint` is `TriPoint`, but is that really the case? Type inference should allow you to call `CallShortestPath` with no type parameters at all the compiler will infer the appropriate types based on the parameters passed to it.

Comment: In many cases it is true yes, but in general not. This is especially so for the methods taking more than one generic parameter.

Comment: `CalcShortestPath` in your example has more than one generic parameter, and yet I was able to call `CalcShortestPath(new HexGrid(), new HexPoint(), new HexPoint())` just fine (both type parameters are correctly inferred). I'd be interested to see a concrete example from your situation where it falls down. (Also, if you could include "@Iridium" when replying to my comment, I'll be notified of the reply, rather than having to check back here periodically!)

Comment: how much points or grid types do you actually have ? This is usually a 'design' problem - you might be overdoing it with generics, I second what @Jean Hominal said for the most part. So, i think you should ask yourself a question do you really need all parameters to be generic - i.e. do you have unlimited or hundreds (dozens) of those types. If not - you'd need to break it down into whats' important and not and use more good old OO + generics where needed. If 'yes', then you have a complex system, again, some restructuring is needed.

Comment: @Iridium, I struggled for almost an hour to find a minimal example (I actually don't know the exact rules for when the compiler can infer types correctly). I added the example. As you will see, if you add another parameter, it can help the compiler out.

Comment: Just a random thought (after a headache-clouded skim), but would adding an interface that expresses the duals help? Like IDual<TPoint>, where TriPoint would implement IDual<HexPoint>, etc?

Comment: @JerKimball It will take me a while to see, but in my minimal examples it does help indeed... I would feel a bit stupid if the solution can be so simple. (There will still be a few hectic cases, but only for methods that rely on that interface... most don't).

Comment: @JerKimball It worked like a charm. The change was much simpler than I thought, and now the code looks much less terrifying (I could remove type parameters from 100s of lines). It also solved another issue very nicely: one of the parameters lead to a potentially infinite chain, which I had to solve by implementing "NotImplemented" types, which is quite nasty. Now all I have to do is not implement the appropriate interface. I may still combine it with  what Jean Hominal suggested, but if you can answer as an answer then I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'm not in a point grubbing mood, but in the interests of having an example here, I'll type one up tomorrow (or you could "self-answer) if you feel so inclined) - glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, gonna throw up an answer based on the throwaway idea I talked about in the comments...

The basic gist was "Define a type that conveys this concept of point duality, and use that in your relevant signatures so as to give the compiler the hints it needs"

One thing you should read whenever you hit the dreaded "Type cannot be inferred from usage" error:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

In that, Messr. Lippert spells out the harsh truth that only the parameters of the signature are checked during this inference stage, NOT the constraints. So we have to be a tiny bit more "specific" here.

First, let's define our "duality relationship" - I should note this is **one way** to set up these relationships, there are (in theory) an infinite variety of them.

```
public interface IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
    where TPoint: IPoint<TPoint>, IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint>
    where TDualPoint: IPoint<TDualPoint>, IDual<TDualPoint, TPoint>
{}
```

Now we go back and retrofit our existing signatures:

```
public interface IPoint<TPoint> 
   where TPoint:IPoint<TPoint> 
{}
class TriPoint : IPoint<TriPoint>, IDual<TriPoint,HexPoint>
{}
class HexPoint : IPoint<HexPoint>, IDual<HexPoint,TriPoint> 
{
   // Normally you would rotate the point
   public HexPoint Rotate240(){ return new HexPoint();} 
}
```

And likewise on the "secondary types", the grids:

```
interface IGrid<TPoint, TDualPoint> 
   where TPoint: IPoint<TPoint>, IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint>  
   where TDualPoint : IPoint<TDualPoint>, IDual<TDualPoint, TPoint> 
{
    TDualPoint GetDualPoint(TPoint point);
}
class HexGrid : IGrid<HexPoint, TriPoint>
{
    public TriPoint GetDualPoint(HexPoint point)
    {
        return new TriPoint();
    }
}
class TriGrid : IGrid<TriPoint, HexPoint> 
{
    public HexPoint GetDualPoint(TriPoint point)
    {
        return new HexPoint();
    }
}
```

And finally on our utility methods:

```
static class Algorithms
{  
   public static IEnumerable<TPoint> TransformShape<TPoint, TDualPoint>(
      IEnumerable<IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint>> shape, 
      Func<TPoint, TPoint> transform)
   where TPoint : IPoint<TPoint>, IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint>   
   where TDualPoint : IPoint<TDualPoint>, IDual<TDualPoint, TPoint> 
   {
      return 
         from TPoint point in shape
            select transform(point);
   }

   public static IEnumerable<TPoint> TransformShape<TPoint, TDualPoint>(
      IGrid<TPoint, TDualPoint> grid, 
      IEnumerable<IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint>> shape, 
      Func<TPoint, TPoint> transform)
   where TPoint : IPoint<TPoint>, IDual<TPoint, TDualPoint>   
   where TDualPoint : IPoint<TDualPoint>, IDual<TDualPoint, TPoint> 
   {
      return 
         from TPoint point in shape
            //where transform(point) is in grid
            select transform(point);
   }
}
```

Note the signature on the method - we are saying "Hey, this list of things we're giving you, it absolutely has dual points", which is what's going to allow code like so:

```
  HexGrid hexGrid = new HexGrid();      
  List<HexPoint> hexPointShape = new List<HexPoint>(); //Add some items

  //Compiles
  var rotatedShape1 = Algorithms
      .TransformShape(
     hexGrid,
     hexPointShape, 
     point => point.Rotate240())
    .ToList();

  //Compiles   
  var rotatedShape2 = Algorithms
      .TransformShape<HexPoint, TriPoint>(
     hexPointShape, 
     point => point.Rotate240())
    .ToList();     

  //Did not compile, but does now!
  var rotatedShape3 = Algorithms
      .TransformShape(
      hexPointShape, 
      point => point.Rotate240())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 - a good design extrapolation - even though I'm quite sure you don't need a slap on the back :)

Comment: @NSGaga - Aww, I take any ego-boost I can get. ;)

Comment: Yes, it works nicely :) If the idea is taken a bit further, we can move the `GetDualPoint` method into a `IDualGrid` interface, and then get rid of the additional type parameters in the utility methods if they do not make use of the duals. This significantly reduces the complexity of the declarations. It also releives the implementer of `IGrid` to implement dual methods if it is not required for the algorithms he needs to use.

Answer (score 2):

I once hit a case of generics overload where I had a set of 5 generic interfaces, and each of them was parametrized according to each of the implementations of the generic interfaces. That was a wonderful design in theory, as it meant that all method parameters and return types were checked statically.

In practice, after wrangling with that design for a while, and realizing that it meant that any method that took any of these interfaces as an argument would have to specify all of the type parameters, I decided to simply make these interfaces non generic and use runtime casts for method parameters instead of having the compiler enforce it.

I would suggest simplifying the design - up to, possibly, dropping all type parameters from the interfaces.

A possible solution, depending on the kind of algorithms you want to define, could be to define additional interfaces, that take less type parameters, and in exchange expose less methods.

e.g.:

```
interface IPoint 
{
    int X {get;}
    int Y {get;}
    // Maybe you do not need that one.
    IPoint Translate(IPoint dual);
}
interface IPoint<TPoint> : IPoint
    where TPoint : IPoint<TPoint>
{
    new TPoint Translate(TPoint dual);
}
```

Now, you can define an algorithm that takes an `IPoint` without having the information about the dual point type leak through. Note however that having generic and non-generic interfaces for the same thing can make the design even more complex.

Without more information about the real interfaces, and how you need to use it, I do not really know what precise modifications to suggest.

Do not forget that you should balance implementation complexity and readability - if even you have trouble rewriting the method type parameters, then think about people that will use your objects without having written them!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot so quickly determine whether this will work or not, but it is definitely something to consider. For me, the most important feature is that using the library should be easy and client code clear (and "safe" / correct). Your answer also made me think of the possibility of moving the generic algorithms to the Grid classes (they can call generic ones if required)...